# On the sum of random coin flips

Tags: probability, random-walk, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

If I toss a (fair) coin $N$ times, I expect to see an excess of tails/heads by roughly $\sqrt{N}$. Is this true? If yes, according to what theorem? If no, is there a way to quantify a bound for such possible excess?

([linked](https://(linked:%20https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762699/on-the-brownian-motion-and-law-of-large-numbers?noredirect=1#762705)))

Comment: Relevant: [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: $\sqrt{N}$ is not a bound, but instead the standard deviation of the distribution of the signed  difference between Head and Tails.  The bounds are $\pm N$, and the most likely signed difference is $0$ or $\pm1$ depending on whether you have an even or odd number of tosses.  These change with absolute differences, but the expected value is about $\sqrt{\dfrac{2N}{\pi}}$ for large $N$, and the most likely values are $2$ or $1$ depending on parity.

Comment: Is it the Law of Iterated Logarithm? $S_N\approx\sqrt{N\ln(\ln N))}$?

Comment: This also falls under the rubric of a 1D balanced random walk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of heads when tossing a coin $N$ times is a binomial random variable, $\sim B(N,p)$. The variance of a binomial is $Npq, q=1-p$. Given a coin is fair, $p=q=1/2$, the expected  value of (absolute) difference of heads and tails is 2 standard deviations, it is $$2 \sqrt{N/4}=\sqrt{N}$$

So you are correct.